# Western Digital MyCloud EX2 SLOW

Tags: nas

My Western Digital MyCloud EX2 has become very slow.  No recent changes to device or network.

Logging in to web interface often times out and if it logs on it takes a minute or more to load the main management page.  Sometimes logon fails and must be attempted again.  Often reports "this page not responding" with option to "Wait" or Cancel. That happens on any page once logged on.

It has the latest firmware (2.12.127) and has been running it for a year or more.  I know this firmware is no longer supported and has a security issue.  The device is not connected to Internet. No longer supported by WD.

The NAS is connected by CAT5e cable to router.  It has a static IPv4 address.  Link speed has been tried as Auto and Gigabit with no change in performance.  Still slow to access via web interface.

It has two WD Red drives in a RAID 1 array. Drives pass SMART and RAID status is normal.  Not showing rebuilding.  Diagnostics of NAS report "Healthy"

It has Plex media server installed and is also used to backup files from two Windows 10 systems.  I had turned off Plex in earlier diagnostic testing but no change in performance. About 1.44TB free.

Because interface is so slow to respond, it is hard to say status of CPU and RAM and network but network activity on LAN in general is low.  Drive temps report low.  Drive lights show activity but cannot see any backup activity and no streaming from Plex media.

When able to load "Device Activity" it shows 72% RAM used and 57 processes.  Given how slow the web page loads, hard to say if numbers are steady or a moment in time.  Trying to get process list usually times out over and over. Every time over the past hour I have been able to get status loaded, it shows no network activity

I can see three processes for smbd using about 81% of RAM A number of httpd running.  Tried to get screen shots of all 57 processes but response is way too slow.

Hate to replace this as it has worked well and is not heavily used with only two users and Plex streaming from time to time.

After many tries have some detailed SMART data.  NAS so unresponsive it takes a while waiting for pages to load.
I removed drives and attached to external USB to run Crystal Disk Info

The NAS can't be shut down by web interface so power removal is it. Did that to get drives out to test and web responsive on restart.  Integrated System Test reports all is well.  No errors in logs.  Shutting down Plex again and stopping all backup activity to see what happens

[image: NAS Drive 1 SMART]
[image: NAS Drive 2 SMART]

Comment: Can you get the SMART info for the disk?

Comment: Diagnostic of the NAS reports drive temps 45 degrees and status healthy.  Trying for more detail but it has taken 35 minutes to get this data displayed.

Comment: It seems like the NAS is running low on RAM and is therefore swapping heavily. Plex might be a little too heavy for 512MB RAM

Comment: Plex was working perfectly for several years.  No changes to size of media library in that time.  No significant change is backup files.  No added users.  Streaming is very limited.  Often once or twice a month. NAS is isolated from Internet.  I had turned off Plex in earlier diagnostic testing but no change in performance.